# VB6 IDE - endless save-error-save-error loop preventing saving changes or exiting

Tags: vb6

Scenario:

- Load VB6 project in the VB6 IDE
- Introduce some syntax error
- Attempt to exit the IDE
- It asks if I want to save - click YES
- *It warns about a syntax error* *as though I had attempted to run the program*
- *It does not save the file*
- *It does not exit*

The last three points will just cycle forever until there are no syntax errors.

---

If instead I click NO to the save dialog, then it does exit but of course loses all my changes.

---

This is a newer PC and a fresh install of VB6. I can't remember this normally happening on my old PC. Did I miss some setting or something?

---

The type of error involved in this are labelled "Compile error" such as, for instance:

[image]

Comment: This might have something to do with either auto-save before run option in setup, or similar compile to p-code/exe setting, but I'm just throwing out ideas.  I have never experienced this in VB6 myself.

Answer (score 0):

The [VBAdvance IDE plugin](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/) detects when files have been edited outside the IDE. This has provided a strange workaround or avoidance of  this problem.

If I edit the file having the syntax error outside of VB6, then VBAdvance will ask me if I want to reload it. Click OK, and then VB6 will close without flagging more syntax errors! Seems like this forces it to 'reset' something internal.

This is better than nothing but requires manually editing files outside the IDE so is far from ideal.